# What variables control what format the time and date are in in Firefox and what else does that affect?

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, locale

My main question is:

1. **What (env) variables control what format the time and date are in in Firefox and what else does that affect (UI, spell-check)?**

I tried changing locale settings, packages, Firefox language packs and Firefox settings, but I couldn't figure out a combination to give me the desired result again:

2. **How can I use Firefox in en-US (spell-check and, less importantly, UI), but have time displayed in 24h format (and date as anything except for mm DD yy)?**

In some previous version of Kubuntu I "fixed" my problem by setting some general parts of my locale to en-GB, but that had the undesirable side effect of changing Pidgin's spell check from en-US to en-GB. This time I cannot even reproduce that result (despite having been taking notes).

I tried many suggestion from StackExchange and elsewhere and none of them worked for me. Luckily I remembered in my desperation that in addition to *answering* questions on StackExchange I can also *ask* questions!

---

### Outputs and status:

I am using Firefox 66.0.3 (64-bit) on Kubuntu 18.04.

In Firefox > Addons > Languages, I have both en-US and en-GB installed.

In Firefox > Preferences > Language and Appearance > Language: For both UI language and website display language I tried both en-US and en-GB without any change.

In Firefox from chrome://global/locale/intl.properties:

```
# This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
# License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
# file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.

# LOCALIZATION NOTE (intl.accept_languages):
# This is a comma-separated list of valid BCP 47 language tags.
#
# Begin with the language tag of your locale. Next, include language
# tags for other languages that you expect most users of your locale to be
# able to speak, so that their browsing experience degrades gracefully if
# content is not available in their primary language.
#
# It is recommended that you include "en-US, en" at the end of the list as a
# last resort. However, if you know that users of your locale would prefer a
# different variety of English, or if they are not likely to understand
# English at all, you may opt to include a different English language tag, or
# to exclude English altogether.
#
# For example, the Breton [br] locale might consider including French and
# British English in their list, since those languages are commonly spoken in
# the same area as Breton:
# intl.accept_languages=br, fr-FR, fr, en-GB, en
intl.accept_languages=en-US, en

# LOCALIZATION NOTE (font.language.group):
# This preference controls the initial setting of the language drop-down menu
# in the Content > Fonts & Colors > Advanced preference panel.
#
# Set it to the value of one of the menuitems in the "selectLangs" menulist in
# http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/preferences/fonts.xul
font.language.group=x-western

# LOCALIZATION NOTE (intl.charset.detector):
# This preference controls the initial setting for the character encoding
# detector. Valid values are ja_parallel_state_machine for Japanese, ruprob
# for Russian and ukprob for Ukrainian and the empty string to turn detection
# off. The value must be empty for locales other than Japanese, Russian and
# Ukrainian.
intl.charset.detector=

# LOCALIZATION NOTE (pluralRule): Pick the appropriate plural rule for your
# language. This will determine how many plural forms of a word you will need
# to provide and in what order.
# See: http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Localization_and_Plurals
pluralRule=1

# LOCALIZATION NOTE (intl.menuitems.alwaysappendaccesskeys, intl.menuitems.insertseparatorbeforeaccesskeys):
# Valid values are: true, false, <empty string>
# Missing preference or empty value equals false.
intl.menuitems.alwaysappendaccesskeys=
intl.menuitems.insertseparatorbeforeaccesskeys=true
```

Output of `locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=et_EE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=et_EE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=et_EE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=et_EE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=et_EE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Output of `printenv | grep LC_`:

```
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=et_EE.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=et_EE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_ADDRESS=et_EE.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=et_EE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=et_EE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Output of `localectl status`:

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
                  LC_NUMERIC=et_EE.UTF-8
                  LC_TIME=et_EE.UTF-8
                  LC_MONETARY=et_EE.UTF-8
                  LC_PAPER=et_EE.UTF-8
                  LC_NAME=et_EE.UTF-8
                  LC_ADDRESS=et_EE.UTF-8
                  LC_TELEPHONE=et_EE.UTF-8
                  LC_MEASUREMENT=et_EE.UTF-8
                  LC_IDENTIFICATION=et_EE.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc105
```

Output of `locale -a`:

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
et_EE.utf8
```

Maybe it is also relevant that if I launch Firefox from a terminal I get the following warnings:

```
(firefox:15865): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:27:21.499: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:15933): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:27:21.873: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:15982): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:27:22.569: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:16024): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:27:24.441: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:16152): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:27:26.382: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

Comment: It's odd that FF complains about locale if you don't get similar messages when running the `locale` command. What does the command `locale -a` output?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I added that to the question.

Comment: I see that the German locale has not been generated. Try `sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks! That fixed everything.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Maybe you can paste that as an answer so I can mark this question as solved and give you some internet-points for your help?

Comment: Please feel free to submit an answer yourself. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. :)

Comment: Thanks. Btw I have since then found Swedish English to have the most likable time format. :D

Comment: There is no Swedish English locale AFAIK. Do you possibly mean en_DK (Danish)? That locale tries to comply with the ISO standard.

Comment: The last line from `printenv | grep LC_` for me is `LC_TIME=en_SE.UTF-8`. I looked through all the time format options on Kubuntu 18.04 and this one was most similar to ISO-8601.

Comment: That locale does not exist. The fact that you succeeded in having KDE still set it is a KDE bug. I'm pretty sure that you'll see some complaint if you run the `locale` terminal command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113025/discussion-between-carolus-and-gunnar-hjalmarsson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using German locale `de_DE.UTF-8`, but it was missing from the output of `locale -a` (as visible in the question).

The solution (thanks to @GunnarHjalmarsson) was to generate that as well with:

```
sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
```